# Does a person in a position of power ordering his subordinate to perform a sinful act incur a bigger sin?

Tags: karma, sin, kings

For ex if a maharaja or king orders his minister to perform an act, which is called sinful in smritis. Will the king get sinful reaction bigger than minister or equal or only minister will get the sin since minister has to do the act.

Is it also possible that if someone commits a sin knowingly, but from a position of utter helplessness, then the one who commands (the powerful) will get all sins since they forced the helpless person to do a sin?

Comment: A king incur sin if he has ordered. A minister or anyone who has committed sin because lets say king would have punished him for not complying will not incur sin

Comment: Yes.. Punya and Papa are shared to others who support a person (doer of an action).. Devatas had to suffer from hands of tarakasura because they attended Daksha Yajña.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The best example is Gandhari - she never cursed the pandavas who killed her sons and destroyed the Kaurava army under the guidance of Krishna, using adharmic means.  She only cursed Krishna, who had the power to prevent the slaughter and still allowed it to take place.

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11023.htm

> By good luck, thou seest not today thy son slain in battle, and Bhurishrava deprived of life, and thy widowed daughters-in-law plunged into grief. By good luck, thou seest not the golden umbrella of that illustrious warrior who had the sacrificial stake for the device on his banner, torn and broken on the terrace of his car. There the black-eyed wives of Bhurishrava are indulging in piteous lamentations, surrounding their lord slain by Satyaki. Afflicted with grief on account of the slaughter of their lords, those ladies, indulging in copious lamentations, are falling down on the earth with their faces towards the ground, and slowly approaching thee, O Keshava! Alas, why did Arjuna of pure deeds perpetrate such a censurable act, since he struck off the arm of a heedless warrior who was brave and devoted to the performance of sacrifices. Alas, Satyaki did an act that was still more sinful, for he took the life of a person of restrained soul while sitting in the observance of the praya vow. Alas, O righteous one, thou liest on the ground, slain unfairly by two foes." Even thus, O Madhava, those wives of Bhurishrava are crying aloud in woe. There, those wives of that warrior, all possessed of slender waists, are placing upon their laps the lopped off arm of their lord and weeping bitterly!

> "Here is that arm which used to invade the girdles, grind the deep bosoms, and touch the navel, the thighs, and the hips, of fair women, and loosen the ties of the drawers worn by them! Here is that arm which slew foes and dispelled the fears of friends, which gave thousands of kine and exterminated Kshatriyas in battle! In the presence of Vasudeva himself, Arjuna of unstained deeds, lopped it off thy heedless self while thou wert engaged with another in battle. What, indeed, wilt thou, O Janardana, say of this great feat of Arjuna while speaking of it in the midst of assemblies. What also will the diadem-decked Arjuna himself say of it?" Censuring thee in this way, that foremost of ladies hath stopped at last. The co-wives of that lady are piteously lamenting with her as if she were their daughter-in-law!

https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m11/m11024.htm

> "Gandhari said, ‘The Pandavas and the Dhartarashtras, O Krishna, have both been burnt. Whilst they were thus being exterminated, O Janardana, why wert thou indifferent to them? Thou wert competent to prevent the slaughter, for thou hast a large number of followers and a vast force. Thou hadst eloquence, and thou hadst the power (for bringing about peace). Since deliberately, O slayer of Madhu, thou wert indifferent to this universal carnage, therefore, O mighty-armed one, thou shouldst reap the fruit of this act. By the little merit I have acquired through waiting dutifully on my husband, by that merit so difficult to attain, I shall curse thee, O wielder of the discus and the mace! Since thou wert indifferent to the Kurus and the Pandavas whilst they slew each other, therefore, O Govinda, thou shalt be the slayer of thy own kinsmen! In the thirty-sixth year from this, O slayer of Madhu, thou shalt, after causing the slaughter of thy kinsmen and friends and sons, perish by disgusting means in the wilderness. The ladies of thy race, deprived of sons, kinsmen, and friends, shall weep and cry even as these ladies of the Bharata race!’"

Answer (score 0):

"Position of power ordering subordinate"

Answer:
राजविद्या राजगुह्यं पवित्रमिदमुत्तमम्‌ । प्रत्यक्षावगमं धर्म्यं सुसुखं कर्तुमव्ययम्‌ ॥
The above sloka gives importance of Pavithram (Purity by all means). If such person / group governs a region there may not be sins accumulated.

Ordering subordinate is usual and seen in any region of world.

But if ruler or ruler groups dont know राजविद्या, obviously subordinate may increase sinners in society.

Conclusion: YES, Big sins by Rulers result in bigger sins by subordinates.

Historical examples: Before 1st Century

1. King Sishupaala sending slaves against GOD KRISHNA
2. King Duryodhana sending Duschashana against Draupadi
3. Kings ordering horse sacrifices physically without consent/happiness of BRAAHMANA (head priest)

After 11th century

1. Kings who sent slave tribes to invade India for IRON ORE and GOLD deposits, example GHAZNI on Amritasaras
2. Kings who sent Nawabs for land tax on captured lands
3. Kings who propagated their languages without any purpose / values applicable to local areas
4. Kings who ordered demolishment of Sacred temples and manuscripts etc

Without the help of subordinates which King "stood on his own legs"- meaning achieved everything independently??
HENCE SINS ARE EXTREME in Kaliyuga by rulers failing to know RAAJAVIDHYA